# Encrypt or Hide XML files to use in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, air, archive

I'm making an Adobe Air desktop game in Actionscript 3 and I'm storing level data in XML files.

I was wondering, is there any way to put all the XML files into some sort of archive (like a .DAT archive) so that users cannot view them?

If not that, then how could I encrypt the files so that the XML could not be edited manually?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance,

Zoron19

Comment: I have another solution: you can save data as a binary .dat file (store your data a ByteArray)...you will have 100% control over the specification of the file (header, layout structure, etc.) and unless you publish the specs, it will take a while for people for figure out how parse the bytearray.

Comment: You can write them binary into some custom file, flash can do this with ByteArray. I am successfully doing this in my game.  XML is very open and very changable, so you might want to avoid it. Otherwise, any encryption algrithm should work.

Comment: does my answer work for you?

Comment: Nah, I decided not to bother and just make a flash version of the game. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 1):

I did it last year using [as3crypto](https://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/). Very easy to use :)

What you want to do is encrypt the file when writing it to disk, and decrypt it when loading it in your code.

[Here](http://www.newyyz.com/ntgstage/ntgsite/2009/12/encryption-and-decryption-with-as3crypto-library/) you can find a tutorial. It's Flex based but you can use the parts of coding/decoding your file

Answer (score 0):

You can use encrypted SQLite database with Air, so can store your XML there. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS8AFC5E35-DC79-4082-9AD4-DE1A2B41DAAF.html